# How can I lookup which objects in a MongoDB collection contain a field with specific information in it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a web application which allows user to bring up a page, called "Cruise Ship". On that page, I would like users to be able to see other cruise ships from the same cruise line. My MongoDB model for the ships has cruiseLine as a field. This is how I have my view controller structured:

```
exports.getShip = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const ship = await Ship.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }).populate({
    path: 'reviews',
    fields: 'review rating user displayDate ratingsQuantity',
  });
  const reviewCount = await Review.count();
  const allShips = await Ship.find();

  if (!ship) {
    return next(new AppError('Page does not exist. Please try again.', 404));
  }

  res.status(200).render('ship', {
    title: `${ship.shipName} Reviews`,
    ship,
    allShips,
    reviewCount,
  });
});
```

I tried including something like this, but it returns undefined:

```
const cruiseLineInfo = await Ship.find({ cruiseLine: ship.cruiseLine })
```

In my attempt, I was hoping that ship.cruiseLine would be interpreted as a the cruise line for the specific ship page (example, "Carnival Cruise Line") and then cruiseLineInfo would contain all of the ship objects that matched the find query. But alas, it has not worked. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this in Pug using inline Javascript, a loop and an "if" statement.

```
- var thisCruiseLine = ship.cruiseLine
- var thisShipName = ship.shipName
        each ship in allShips
                if ship.cruiseLine == thisCruiseLine && ship.shipName != thisShipName
                        p #{ship.shipName}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mongoose, `.find()` only builds a query, but that doesn’t run the query immediately. You could build a query first and then run it some time later.

To execute your query, you can either add a callback as a parameter to `.find()` or chain an `.exec()` right behind it:

```
const cruiseLineInfo = await Ship.find({ cruiseLine: ship.cruiseLine }, (error, response) => {
  // do something with the response
})
```

In your case, the `.exec()` seems more appropriate:

```
const cruiseLineInfo = await Ship.find({ cruiseLine: ship.cruiseLine }).exec()
```